How do I avoid pickling error whilst defining a function within a function?
I am trying to create a list of functions that act as controllers for a machine learning project.
Each function in the list is created at instantiation with its own parameters, and then each one has to be run an arbitrary number of times with (an) argument(s) to evaluate them. Things are slow so I have to parallelize it, but I'm having pickling issues.
I have reduced the script to this
import multiprocessing as mp

class task():
    def parallelizationWrap(self):
        poolSize = 5
        with mp.Pool(poolSize) as pool:
            for _ in pool.imap(self.parallelizationFunc, range(poolSize)):
                pass    

    def serialWrap(self):
        for _ in range(5):
            self.parallelizationFunc()

    def setup(self, unusedVar=None):
        vallist = [1,2,3,4,5]
        self.funclist = []
        for i in range(5):
            def tempfunc(argument, parameter=vallist[i]):
                print(parameter*argument)
            self.funclist.append(tempfunc)

    def parallelizationFunc(self, unuserVar=None):
        for step in range(25):
            for j in range(5):
                result = self.funclist[j](step)
                simulation.sendSignalToCorrectAgent(result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.freeze_support()

    c1 = task()
    c1.setup()
    c1.parallelizationWrap()
    # c1.serialWrap()

which gives me the error code
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'task.setup.<locals>.tempfunc'

I have considered just saving the parameters instead of the function directly, but that doesn't give me the flexibility I need, since the function can change.
I have also tried making it global as recommended here, but that gave me a similar pickling issue: _pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function tempfunc at 0x000001861D0A3E20>: it's not the same object as __main__.tempfunc

I can smuggle the function in as a string using the exec function later, bypassing multiprocessings issues:
Replace task.setup and task.parallelizationFunc, defining the tempFunc functions as strings and extracting them using Python 3's strange exec function, as such:
class taskWithFunctioningParallelization(task):
    def setup(self, unusedVar=None):
        vallist = [1,2,3,4,5]
        self.funclist = []
        for i in range(5):
            funcString = f"""def tempFunc(argument, parameter={vallist[i]}):
    print(parameter*argument)"""
            self.funclist.append(funcString)

    def parallelizationFunc(self, unusedVar=None):
        for step in range(10):
            for j in range(5):
                funcString = self.funclist[j]
                d = {}
                exec(funcString, d)
                controllerFunc = d[list(d.keys())[1]]
                controllerFunc(step)


The pickle protocol that is used by multiprocessing to pass data between processes has very limited capabilties when it comes to passing functions. The functions are passed by name, not by copying their code around (which would be a huge security risk, among other things), so functions that don't have a globally accessible name can't easily be used.
That explains the exceptions you're seeing, but doesn't really tell you what to do about it. Looking at your example code, the issue seems to be that you want to run the same underlying code (a multiplication in the example, but probably something more complicated in reality) with two varying arguments. I'd suggest pushing both of those up to the level of the parallelization, and write the code like this:
import multiprocessing as mp
import itertools as it

def low_level_operation(AB):
    A, B = AB
    return A * B

def run_in_parallel(As, Bs):
    poolSize = 5
    with mp.Pool(poolSize) as pool:
        for result in pool.imap(low_level_operation, it.product(As, Bs)):
            pass # or do something with the result


Ah, I see I missed a detail. You interpreted parallelizationFunc as only needing to run one of the listed funcs each, right? Unfortunately I need to run each of these functions several time per individual process, and I can't see how I can make it work the way you do. I edited parallelizationFunc to better reflect what I need in that regard.
